# Is it possible to use angularfire2 with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular6

I'm trying to add firebase support to my Angular 6 app but when adding angularfire2

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase
```

I get a lot of warning saying I must use Angular 5. For example

```
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Is it possible to use angularfire2 with Angular 6 today?

I get this error when compiling:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/rrr/Projects/ng6test/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2720: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements class 'FirebaseApp'. Did you mean to extend 'FirebaseApp' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.
```

I tried to install rxjs-compat but after that I get another warning

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2720: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements class 'FirebaseApp'. Did you mean to extend 'FirebaseApp' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
```

Comment: There is a known issue about this at github (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1576) what you want to do is npm install firebase@4.12.1

Comment: Did you find the solution? if not, try upgrading angularfire2 to latest version: 5.0.0-rc.7.2-next - and firebase to ^4.13.1 with rxjs-compat installed at v.6.. I've got my project working with these versions and angular v. 6. Make sure to check the console that it actually installed those versions. Let me know

Comment: @ChrisEenberg is not working i update "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7.2-next", and "firebase": "^4.13.1","rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",still is giving error node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFireModule'

Answer (score 4):

I have tried and I cannot make Angular 6 work with any version of AngularFire2 (latest version: 5.0.0-rc.7.2-next). I guess we need to wait for next major version of AngularFire2.

Update:
A **temporary** solution is to install `rxjs-compat`.
`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

Comment: rxjs-compat helped with most of the problems, however I am still getting few lines of errors. Could you tell with which version of firebase and angularfire2 you have managed to launch properly?

Comment: @qUest `firebase 4.13.1` and `angualrfire2 5.0.0-rc.7.2-next`. `firebase 5.0+` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
npm install firebase angularfire2@next --save
```

Fixed in pre-released version:

```
angularfire2@next
```

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
"dependencies": 
{
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
"@firebase/app": "^0.3.3",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
"core-js": "^2.5.6",
"firebase": "^5.0.3",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"rxjs": "^6.2.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

@ngModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule

    ]
})
```

environment

```
firebase: {
    apiKey: "apikey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "https://projectId.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "projectId.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)